# What is an obfuscated library?

Tags: obfuscation, terminology

I am reading some articles regarding computer security and malware. I jumped into a graph relating the `# of potentially malicious applications` with the `# of antiviruses`. The graph's caption said `Applications utilizing obfuscated libraries`. As expected, the more antiviruses the less was the chance of malicious applications.

The tag "obfuscation" in SO says:

> Obfuscation is the process by which the code is altered so that a developer finds it much harder to understand clearly what the intended program does or how it operates. The larger the program the greater the obfuscation, as code becomes intertwined linking different segments through out the program.

So is it just a matter of syntax, deliberately making the code more difficult for the programmer to understand? I suppose `obfuscated libraries` pertains to the same thing?

Comment: It means that the workings of the library are obscured. The source code is made less readable. The program logic is turned inside out and upside down so it's not plainly apparent what it's trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind there are two types of obfuscaton

**A. "Manual Obfuscation":** Where the programmer purposefully obfuscates the code, either to prevent it being understood, or for some other reason such as attempting to make the compiled binary smaller, like this amazing piece of C code that is a working chess program

```
B,i,y,u,b,I[411],*G=I,x=10,z=15,M=1e4;X(w,c,h,e,S,s){int t,o,L,E,d,O=e,N=-M*M,K
=78-h<<x,p,*g,n,*m,A,q,r,C,J,a=y?-x:x;y^=8;G++;d=w||s&&s>=h&&v 0,0)>M;do{_ o=I[
p=O]){q=o&z^y _ q<7){A=q--&2?8:4;C=o-9&z?q["& .$  "]:42;do{r=I[p+=C[l]-64]_!w|p
==w){g=q|p+a-S?0:I+S _!r&(q|A<3||g)||(r+1&z^y)>9&&q|A>2){_ m=!(r-2&7))P G[1]=O,
K;J=n=o&z;E=I[p-a]&z;t=q|E-7?n:(n+=2,6^y);Z n<=t){L=r?l[r&7]*9-189-h-q:0 _ s)L
+=(1-q?l[p/x+5]-l[O/x+5]+l[p%x+6]*-~!q-l[O%x+6]+o/16*8:!!m*9)+(q?0:!(I[p-1]^n)+
!(I[p+1]^n)+l[n&7]*9-386+!!g*99+(A<2))+!(E^y^9)_ s>h||1<s&s==h&&L>z|d){p[I]=n,O
[I]=m?*g=*m,*m=0:g?*g=0:0;L-=X(s>h|d?0:p,L-N,h+1,G[1],J=q|A>1?0:p,s)_!(h||s-1|B
-O|i-n|p-b|L<-M))P y^=8,u=J;J=q-1|A<7||m||!s|d|r|o<z||v 0,0)>M;O[I]=o;p[I]=r;m?
*m=*g,*g=0:g?*g=9^y:0;}_ L>N){*G=O _ s>1){_ h&&c-L<0)P L _!h)i=n,B=O,b=p;}N=L;}
n+=J||(g=I+p,m=p<O?g-3:g+2,*m<z|m[O-p]||I[p+=p-O]);}}}}Z!r&q>2||(p=O,q|A>2|o>z&
!r&&++C*--A));}}}Z++O>98?O=20:e-O);P N+M*M&&N>-K+1924|d?N:0;}main(){Z++B<121)*G
++=B/x%x<2|B%x<2?7:B/x&4?0:*l++&31;Z B=19){Z B++<99)putchar(B%x?l[B[I]|16]:x)_
x-(B=F)){i=I[B+=(x-F)*x]&z;b=F;b+=(x-F)*x;Z x-(*G=F))i=*G^8^y;}else v u,5);v u,
1);}}
```

called [Toledo Nanochess](http://www.nanochess.org/chess3.html) developed by Mexican Oscar Toledo Gutiérrez, a five-time winner of the International Obfuscated C Code Contest (IOCCC).

**B. "Automated Obfuscation":** This is where code which compiles using just-in-time compilation, code that can be decompiled exactly, undergoes an automatized process of "complexifying" and obfuscating the code without affecting the codes performance at runtime.

I hope this helps.